# Replace text characters matching word 'cart' replace with img icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to replace the word '`cart`' through out my entire website document with an image icon or `img src` is it possible to only target the word '`cart`' and do so?

Comment: _is it possible to only target the word 'cart' and do so?_  In short YES!!! :)

Comment: Yes it is possible using `replace` function but why you want to replace like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. Something like this should work:

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(new RegExp("cart", 'g'), "<img src='#'/>"))
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/c7queker/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `replace` method:

```js
$('div').html(function(_,t){
  var src = 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/typicons-2/24/shopping-cart-24.png';
  return t.replace(/cart/g, '<img src="'+src+'">')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>I would like to use jQuery to replace the word 'cart' through out my entire website document with an image icon or img src is it possible to only target the word 'cart' and do so?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use all identifiable jquery which may produce you the desired result and then use the following jquery code sample to replace all carts with images:

```
$('.container ul li a').html(function(i,html) {
    return html.replace('cart', '<img src = "yourImgURL" alt = "' + html + '" />');
});
```